# Copy data from one column to another column in a different table conditioned on values of another column

Tags: ms-access, multiple-columns

I'm not a DB guy and I've looked around here to look for an answer in similar questions but couldn't find one that solves this particular problem:

I have 2 tables - Each with 3 columns (PrimaryKey1, Table1Coln1, Table1Coln2, PrimaryKey2, Table2Coln1, Table2Coln2).

What I'm trying to do is copy values from Table2Coln2 and paste them into Table1Coln2 wherever values in Table1Coln1 & Table2Coln1 are equal. To complicate matters, there are multiple rows with the same values in both corresponding columns in both tables.

I've tried this:

```
UPDATE Table1
SET Table1.Table1Coln2 = Table2.Table2Coln2
WHERE Table1.Table1Coln1 = Table2.Table2Coln1
```

When I run the query, it opens a dialog box asking me to enter a value for Table2.Table2Coln2 ?!

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: sql server or mysql? They are NOT the same thing and the answer will be different.

Comment: Hi. Sorry. Wrong tag. I'm trying this on Microsoft Access. Let me edit..

Comment: `Table2` is not part of the set, `Table2.Table2Coln2` and `Table2.Table2Coln1` are therefore undefined. Access treats undefined fields as parameters, and shows these dialog box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should Join Table1 and Table2:
'Clasic' SQL (used in MySQL):

```
UPDATE Table1, Table2
SET Table1.Table1Coln2 = Table2.Table2Coln2
WHERE Table1.Table1Coln1 = Table2.Table2Coln1
```

MS Sql (used in Access):

```
UPDATE Table1 Inner Join Table2 On Table1.Table1Coln1 = Table2.Table2Coln1
SET Table1.Table1Coln2 = Table2.Table2Coln2
```